# Unable to initialize a TFS store

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-sdk

I am trying to create a task / work item in Visual Studio Team Services  (previously Visual Studio Online). My code fails because "tfsStore" returns null value causing the exception to be thrown.

```
NetworkCredential myNetCredentials = new NetworkCredential("*****", "******");
ICredentials myCredentials = (ICredentials)myNetCredentials;
Uri tfsUri = new Uri("https://*****.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/");
var tfsServer = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri, myCredentials);
tfsServer.EnsureAuthenticated();
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri);
WorkItemStore tfsStore = tfsServer.GetService<WorkItemStore>(); 
if (tfsStore == null)
{
    throw new Exception("Cannot initialize TFS Store");
}
Project teamProject = tfsStore.Projects["******"];
```

I would appreciate any useful tips as to how to resolve the error.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested the code snippet below on my side, which can create a Task work item successfully, you may have a try:

```
NetworkCredential myNetCredentials = new NetworkCredential("******", "******");
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsUri = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://*****.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection"), myNetCredentials);
WorkItemStore tfsStore = tfsUri.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
         if (tfsStore == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Cannot initialize TFS Store");
            }

         Project teamProject = tfsStore.Projects["*****"];
         WorkItemType workItemType = teamProject.WorkItemTypes["Task"];
         WorkItem Task = new WorkItem(workItemType)
            {
                Title = "APITask",
            };
            Task.Save();
```

Including .net api, you can also use [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#create-a-work-item), which is simply:

```
PATCH https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${workItemTypeName}?api-version={version}
```

Comment: I still get Exception "Cannot initialize TFS store" since tfsStore is null. Thx!

Comment: Uh...This code works fine on my side. Did this code connect to VSTS successfully?

Comment: Yes. I am able to successfully connect to VSTS. However, its failing to instantiate the WorkItemStore. I guess it doesn't matter since I was able to use the REST API to get the code to work. Thanks!